# I need a QuickBasic converter to VB6 or C# or any new programming language

Tags: c#, vb6, quickbasic

Is there a Quickbasic .bas file converter to modern programming languages.

I need to convert the .Bas files i have -written in Quick Basic- to be converted to VB6 or C# or any new programming language.

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to make forward progress copy/pasting old Basic into VB6 (which is not a "new programming language").

Comment: Note: VB 6 is not a "new" programming language. Extended support for VB 6 ended 2008. The current version of Visual Basic is VB 10.

Comment: It depends on your code. Most can be copied and pasted, but will need to be updated for an event driven model.

Comment: i have tried a quickbasic to cpp converter but it didnt work for me http://sourceforge.net/projects/qbasictoc/

Comment: i know vb6 is not a new language but...there is a straight forward conversion from vb6 to vb10 and C#... there is no conversion from quickbasic to these new langauges.

Comment: thanks  sixlettervariables...i will try it

Comment: thanks Deanna for your comments

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no such code converter exists. A lot of code should run - but anything that requires DOS specific functionality will not. You may want to look at QB64 or FreeBasic as potential ways to modernize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps.

http://www.ehow.com/how_10073871_convert-qbasic-visual-basic.html

Comment: Wow...that was fast...thanks a million... what i really need is a converter since the .bas code is very long indeed